# How can i Implement music equaliser as well as visualiser in flutter?

Tags: flutter, package, audio-player, equalizer

I am implementing a music app in a flutter. In the app, I want to implement a music equalizer first, and together with this want to implement a visualizer.

like this : [Qualizer](https://www.androidheadlines.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Equalizer-music-player-booster-app-image-September-2019-600x1066.jpg) and [Visualizer](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRC68Ew1REDzAuXrHIexObf8fGQLKHNVoZgpA&usqp=CAU)

I have used this package [Qualizer](https://pub.dev/packages/equalizer) but it doesn't provide sound null safety. so I need an alternative to this.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do the same thing and I was able to implement an equalizer using this package  [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) but the only problem is that it only worked on Android and I couldn't make it work on IOS, I found an issue on GitHub discussing this matter but it was kinda confusing I'm trying to make it work still [GitHub link](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/pull/658)